# Take the password from an Excel sheet

Tags: excel, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

all the time I log into SQL Developer it is asking me for my password.
I know the opportunity to save the password and that I log in automatically.
But my idea was to save the password in a excel file and to type in a comment in the password line or anywhere else so that the SQLDevloper/Oracle takes the password automatically from there.

Is this possible?

PS: I log in SQL Developer normal and use Excel actually only to import and to export data from my tables.

Comment: where do you log into SQL from? an Excel based query? Or is Excel even in the mix at this point?

Comment: I log in SQL Developer normal and use Excel actually only to import and to export data from my tables.